# htaccess with RewriteRule allow request to a specific folder

Tags: php, .htaccess

I've build my own MVC framework and I have the following .htaccess configuration:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /site/public/zone/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Everything that is passed to the *$url* variable is exploded in an array and then I select the controller from the first value.

However in '*zone*' folder I have another folder called '*res*' that has different resources like photos and videos that I want to access them directly.

How should I configure the .htaccess file so that it rewrites everything as it does now but allow direct request to those resources that are in '*res*' folder?

Comment: You are already doing it ...  Your last RewriteCond says that the RewriteRule only apply if the URL isn't a valid file ... So when you enter an URL for a file that exists in your `res` folder, it should works.

Comment: Yes, I found the bug. It was something else. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `lookahead condition` like this:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /site/public/zone/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^((?!zone/res/).+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L,NC]
```